# Getting an array list of all images on SD card

Tags: java, android, arrays

Can someone give me a hint how to get an array list of all images on my SD card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the Image media store to retrieve the data.

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[] { /*columns you want */, null, null, null);
c.moveToFirst();
while(!c.isLast()) {
// add some data to your array list
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what are COLUMNS?

Comment: The columns in the database. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.html

Comment: Something like that?
Cursor c = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);

Comment: Yes but list all the columns you would want.